# Script that return same response - just test communication

Tags: php

I need to test some android app but I depends of some thing that isn't finished yet. I send get request to site ( example http://www.test.com?a=1&b=1), how to write script in php which always return me same thing( example a=4 ) ?
I need to test communication

Comment: @Pekka should be an answer... Also simply `a=4` outside a `<?php` tag would work.

Comment: @Alexandre true. If that's what the OP means, I'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want it to always the return the same thing, regardless of the query string you send? Just create the file and in it put

```
a=4
```

No need to use PHP for that.

If what you really meant was that you want it to echo the values from the query string.

```
<?php

foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
  echo "$key=$value\n";
}
```

(obvious xss vulnerability)